# Guice3 Singleton is never instantiated in GAE project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, guice-3

I'm new to Guice and already stuck :)

I pretty much copied classes GuiceConfig, OfyFactory and slightly modified Ofy from [Motomapia project](https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/tree/master/java) (which you can browse) using it as s sample.

I created `GuiceServletContextListener` which looks like this

```
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
{
    static class CourierServletModule extends ServletModule
    {
        @Override
        protected void configureServlets()
        {
            filter("/*").through(AsyncCacheFilter.class);
        }
    }

    public static class CourierModule extends AbstractModule
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
            // External things that don't have Guice annotations
            bind(AsyncCacheFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);
        }

        @Provides
        @RequestScoped
        Ofy provideOfy(OfyFactory fact)
        {
            return fact.begin();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)
    {
        super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector()
    {
        return Guice.createInjector(new CourierServletModule(), new CourierModule());
    }
}
```

I added this listener into my web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mine.courierApp.server.GuiceConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- GUICE -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>GuiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>GuiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- My test servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mine.courierApp.server.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

OfyFactory looks like this

```
@Singleton
public class OfyFactory extends ObjectifyFactory
{
    Injector injector;

    @Inject
    public OfyFactory(Injector injector)
    {
        this.injector = injector;

        register(Pizza.class);
        register(Ingredient.class);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T construct(Class<T> type)
    {
        return injector.getInstance(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Ofy begin()
    {
        return new Ofy(super.begin());
    }
}
```

Ofy doesn't have any Guice annotations at all...

```
public class Ofy extends ObjectifyWrapper<Ofy, OfyFactory>
{
    // bunch of helper methods here
}
```

And finally test servlet where I'm trying to use injected field looks like this

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Inject Ofy ofy;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ofy.save(new Pizza());
    }
}
```

Ofy ofy is always null. It's never injected. And it's not injected because OfyFactory is never instantiated, its constructor is never called.

Could you please point what I'm doing wrong? Why my singleton is never created?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of defining `TestServlet` in the web.xml file, try deleting its mapping from web.xml and adding this line in the `configureServlets()` method:

```
serve("/test").with(TestServlet.class);
```

You may also need to bind `TestServlet` as a `Singleton` either by annotating the class with `@Singleton` or by adding a

```
bind(TestServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

line to one of the modules.

What's happening is that Guice is not actually creating your servlet so it isn't able to inject the `Ofy` object.  Guice will only create servlets if it is instructed to do so using a `serve(...).with(...)` binding.  Any servlets defined in the web.xml are outside of Guice's control.

Comment: You're absolutely right. After I posted this question I did exactly what you wrote. Now I'm getting `Error in custom provider, com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access scoped object. Either we are not currently inside an HTTP Servlet request, or you may have forgotten to apply com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter as a servlet filter for this request.`. It works if I remove `@RequestScoped` from Provider. What could be the problem?

Comment: Since the `TestServlet` must be a singleton, you need to inject a `Provider<Ofy>` into `TestServlet` instead if the `Ofy` object needs to be scoped per request, i.e. `@RequestScoped`.  The documentation at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule explains this fairly well.

Comment: It's also in the example - lines 59 to 62 here: https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/blob/master/java/com/motomapia/GuiceConfig.java
and usage on line 40 and 74 here: https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/blob/master/java/com/motomapia/DownloadServlet.java